# Legacy Windows Application in Crossover Asking for Registration - Novice Request

Tags: windows-xp, boot-camp, wine

My wife has a landscape design application that she bought and registered years ago. It runs in Win XP using Bootcamp on a Mac.

I'm trying to run it using WINE (Crossover actually) and eliminate the reboot required by Bootcamp.

It installed and runs just fine, but asks to register upon startup. If I try to register, it attempts to connect to a website that no longer exists and the registration fails.

Any suggestions here? Is there a way to find where the registration code is located on the Win XP partition and somehow get that over to the Crossover app?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: "Is there a way to find where the registration code is located on the Win XP partition and somehow get that over to the Crossover app?" - Find the registry key (if it exists), export it, then import it on the new installation.  If you canot find a key attempt to local the physical file (if it exists).  One of those two things will exists though.

Comment: its also possible that the information is in user isolated storage, in the %appdata% hierarchy for the user it was used with.